# Bash script conditionals simple error

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script given below

```
readlink $MY_LINK

if [$?  != "$TEST_DIR/$PCD_NAME/bin/test2"]; then
    rm $MY_LINK
    ln -s $TEST_DIR/$PCD_NAME/bin/test2 $MY_LINK
fi
```

When I run the script, I am getting the error.

```
./test.sh: line 6: [1: not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: Keep in mind that `[` is the name of a command (there's a built-in version as a performance optimization, but there's also `/usr/bin/[` as the original/external version). Like any other command, whitespace matters -- you can't run `lsfoo.txt` instead of `ls foo.txt`.

Comment: ...that said, another issue is that `$?` is *exit status* -- an unsigned integer. A program will never have an exit status that contains the string `test2` (or any other value that isn't a number between 0 and 255).